# Rally text field access issue

Tags: rally, appsdk2

Developing custom HTML app using Rally:
I want to present a text box and pull value from the enterd data in it. How do i access the text in a rallytextfield while creating a custom html app using App SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the API docs provided - you can find information about a rallytextbox [here](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.TextField).

Specifically, there is a method called:

```
getValue()
```

That you will find in the documentation - I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code which is causing problems on this: 
How do i access the value of the datepicker, i tried the .getValue. It is not able to get the value.Please help

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',       componentCls: 'app',     id: 'appid',        launch: function () {
        var datepickerfrom = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            id: 'datepickerfrom',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'rallytextfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Enter text: ',
                labelWidth: 10
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
        });
        this.add(datepickerfrom);
        button = {
            xtype: 'rallybutton',
            text: 'Generate Report',
            handler: function () {
                console.clear();
                console.log(datepickerfrom.getRawValue());
            },
        };
});
```